# How do I find which file Perl loaded when I use a module?

Tags: perl, module

in Perl, when I do `use <module name> <ver>;`, the system finds the `.pm` file for the library somewhere in the `@INC` path.

Is there a reliable way to which file was actually loaded?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, [`%INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC) contains the full path a module was loaded from.

Example:

```
$ perl -M'Data::Dump qw(pp)' -e 'pp(\%INC)'
{
  "Data/Dump.pm"         => "/usr/share/perl5/Data/Dump.pm",
  "Exporter.pm"          => "/usr/share/perl/5.10/Exporter.pm",
  "List/Util.pm"         => "/usr/lib/perl/5.10/List/Util.pm",
  "Scalar/Util.pm"       => "/usr/lib/perl/5.10/Scalar/Util.pm",
  "XSLoader.pm"          => "/usr/lib/perl/5.10/XSLoader.pm",
  "overload.pm"          => "/usr/share/perl/5.10/overload.pm",
  "strict.pm"            => "/usr/share/perl/5.10/strict.pm",
  "vars.pm"              => "/usr/share/perl/5.10/vars.pm",
  "warnings.pm"          => "/usr/share/perl/5.10/warnings.pm",
  "warnings/register.pm" => "/usr/share/perl/5.10/warnings/register.pm",
}
```

Comment: perl -MData::Dump=pp -e 'pp(\%INC)'

Comment: Your version wins in golf :-D

Comment: So would I be out of luck if I get ' "pp" is not exported by the DBI::Profile module ' if I was checking on DBI::Profile?

Comment: @Marcus: pp is exported by Data::Dump. Not sure what you ran to get that error, but I doubt it was `perl -M'Data::Dump qw(pp)' -e 'pp(\%INC)'`. It should be noted that if you don't have Data::Dump, you can use Data::Dumper instead (or several other similar modules). Or a while loop.

Comment: If you just want to see where DBI::Profile is, I suggest: `perl -MDBI::Profile -E 'say $INC{"DBI/Profile.pm"}'` which outputs /usr/lib/perl5/DBI/Profile.pm here. Note that -E and say is a 5.10 feature; for older perl you'll need to use -e, print, and put a \n at the end.

Comment: @derobert thanks, this clears up the difference between listing all modules versus a single module.  Both very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

If the module has pod documentation, and if you can guarantee that the perldoc utility in your PATH belongs to the same perl that is running your script, then this command will often give you the actual file being found:

```
perldoc -l ModuleName
```

Answer (score 9):

> perl -M'LWP' -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%INC' | grep LWP

This will list out the LWP module location on the disk and also lists out modules loaded inside LWP.

```
      'LWP.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/LWP.pm',
      'LWP/Protocol.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/LWP/Protocol.pm',
      'LWP/UserAgent.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm',
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to look in the `%INC` variable, which records the filename it loaded for the libraries you load with `do`, `require`, or `use`. See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for the details.

Answer (score 5):

There are a good number of modules in CPAN for finding this information, the most likely candidates look to be Module::Find, Module::Which, and Module::Locate.  I'd probably go with Module::Locate:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Locate qw/locate/;

my $to_find = "Some::Module";

print "Perl would use: ", scalar locate($to_find), "\n";
```

In list context locate returns all found copies of Some::Module in order based on @INC.

Edit:
[derobert suggests a much better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341484/which-pm-is-perl-loading#341574), I didn't realize %INC already had it... This module based solution would still be useful if you wanted to know before loading the module where it was going to be loaded from.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner (with a bash wrapper) to determine if a module is installed - and where it will be loaded from:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -M${1} -le "\$mname=\"${1}.pm\";\$mname=~s#::#/#g;print \"$1 INSTALLED AT \$INC{\$mname}\";" 2>/dev/null || echo "${1} NOT INSTALLED"
```

Call it with perl's module name syntax:

```
./find_perl_module  Font::Metrics::Courier
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I found, perl will look in the directories within the path:

```
perl -le 'print foreach @INC'
```

Then it will look in the standard library, and then in the current directory.

That gives you a search order.

My source:

[Extending the library path](http://www.perlhowto.com/extending_the_library_path)

Answer (score 1):

[Module::Mapper](http://search.cpan.org/~darnold/Module-Mapper-1.01/lib/Module/Mapper.pod) provides a way to walk the @INC tree to find modules:

```
perl -MModule::Mapper -MData::Dumper \
-e 'print Dumper( find_sources( UseINC => 1, Modules => [ @ARGV ] ) )' \
list-of-modules-to-locate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instmodsh command: http://perldoc.perl.org/instmodsh.html.

Answer (score 0):

I use the shell script /usr/local/bin/which_perl_module

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! $1 ];then echo "Which perl module should I look for?"; exit; fi

echo -n "You are using: "
perldoc -l $1
echo "which I found by looking in:"
perl -MData::Dump=pp -e 'unshift @INC, '$1'; pp(\@INC)'
```